# pouchdb-server unidirectional replication

Tags: pouchdb

I'm creating an offline app that will be on mobile devices.

I have pouchdb-server that will **bidirectionally** sync to the mobile devices. But I want the pouchdb-server to **unidirectionally** sync to the cloud.

ie. I want my local server to send information but not get anything back. Is there a way to do this?

### Here is a diagram to maybe better explain my scenario:

[image]

I'm trying to figure out what the best method would be to do this type of syncing functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PouchDB makes that really simple. All you have to do is this:

1. Use `db.sync` when you want to keep two databases in sync (bidirectional)
2. Use `db.replicate.to(remoteDb)` when you want to replicate the local DB to the remote DB (unidirectional)
3. Use `db.replicate.from(remoteDb)` when you want to replicate the remote DB to the local one (unidirectional).

Using this, you can create the setup that you have illustrated, like so:

1. Use `db.sync` on the mobile device
2. Use `db.replicate.to(cloudDb)` on your local server

OR

2. If you don't have any application on your local server, set up the replication from your local server to the cloud server from Fauxton (on your local server).

Comment: I understand these functions, but I am running a [pouchdb-server](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb-server). So I am trying to determine how to set that up server side.

Comment: Set up the replication from your local server to the cloud server from Fauxton (on your local server).